# In python whats the opposite of rstrip()

Tags: python

In python while reading a `.txt` file, if we need to remove any character at the end of a line(EOL) including escape sequences like (`\n`, `\t`,etc,.) we use `rstrip('\n')` like this.

But, What is the opposite of the `rstrip()`. I want to add a `\n` or `\t` at the end of each line in a file.

Comment: Note that explicitly providing character(s) such as `str.rstrip('\n')` removes the behaviour of using whitespace characters, and will only strip new lines

Comment: @JonClements, im really sorry to ask this, but i can't understand what you mean by "behaviour of characters" and "will only strip new lines",..
can you please explain a bit.

Comment: If you read the docs: *S.rstrip([chars]) -> str: Return a copy of the string S with trailing whitespace removed. If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.* - so if you specify characters - **only** those are removed... so if you specify `\n` then tabs **won't** be removed

Comment: Thanks all of you people, im new to programming. my question may be dumb, but i learnt something,.. i also would really like to know whats the exact reason to get down voted, and at the same time getting pretty polite responses with various answers with explanation too.

Comment: @arvindh the problem is this isn't really a site to constantly ask beginner questions. I'd go with something like http://learnpythonthehardway.org and get a base of understanding. Then your questions will start to be more appropriate for the site.

Comment: @RobertGrant, a reason always convinces,. thanks for the advice

Comment: The downvoters are probably not the same people who gave you answers. But anyway, it's really not a great question for SO: Google gives `About 416,000 results` for `python add newline to string`. So the downvotes are to let people in the future know that this isn't a very useful question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append the extra character:

```
line + "\n"
```

There is no real 'opposite' to `str.rstrip()`; that method removes an *arbitrary* number of characters, while you rarely would want to add a random number of new characters.

Comment: is there any specific module like rsrtip(),..?

Comment: @arvindh what do you mean by module?

Comment: @JonClements: no. The OP didn't state what they are doing at all, so for all we know they are writing to a file in which case it'd be `fileobj.write(line + '\n')`, for example.

Comment: @arvindh: I'm not sure what you are asking there. `str.rstrip()` is a built-in method, not a module.

Comment: @JonClements, yes,  you are right ,.. my code writes information to a file by copying lines from another file along with information like `timestamp + some data` thats generated while the code is running,.. im using `readline().strip('\n')` to read each line. And then, add the extra information. Then i paste this modified line inside the new file. the problem is, i get all the lines getting printed on to a single line itself.

Comment: @arvindh: To repeat Jon Clements's advice: It's **much** better to use `readline().rstrip()` than `readline().strip('\n')`. Your version only cleans up `\n`, but `.rstrip()` cleans up **all** trailing whitespace on a line. So not only does it get rid of `\n` it also gets rid of spaces and  tabs at the end of the line. And it also removes `\r`, the carriage return character; Windows uses `\r\n` as the line terminator in text files.

Comment: @PM2Ring, thanks a lot, now i get it much more clear'er.

Comment: @PM2Ring: that depends heavily on wether or not that trailing whitespace carries meaning. *Usually* it doesn't but if you have a tab-separated file with the last column(s) empty that'd be.. unwise (even though using the `csv` module would be wiser still).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: True enough. My comment was motivated by the 1st paragraph in the question, as it appears that the OP thought `rstrip('\n')` cleans up tabs as well as newlines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `+` operator :

```
line = line+ '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can use `+`

Other options are

- `line = '{}\n'.format(line)`
- `line = '%s\n'%(line)`
- `line += '\n'`

Another far pulling way would be

```
def opposite_of_rstrip(s):
    return s + '\n'
```

You can now use it as

```
line = opposite_of_rstrip(line)
```

EDIT

- [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) - This is used to do various string formatting operations.

Comment: I'd tend to avoid the overhead of a function call for something as simple as this. FWIW, that function name leaves a lot to be desired, but I don't think it deserves a downvote. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring That's why I mentioned it is a *faaaar pulling way*. It is really stupid to do so

Comment: @arvindh Sure. Check the link https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format